# How to render Dust template on server side

Tags: templates, server-side, dust.js

As my searching on Google, dust can support server-side rendering, so how can i use it on server side?? I just want to run script render on server and send the template to client .

Comment: It's a javascript library so you can use it if you're running NodeJS or you can render directly in the browser. If you're not using javascript then I'd recommend a language specific template library. Otherwise, check out this tutorial: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial

Comment: yep, thanks for your comment. In fact, I've read and followed that tutorial link for my project. And see how it work on the client side. On server side, i use play framework + java , and some cases I want to render dust on server side, so I dont know what is can work with Play if I want to render dust on the server side.

Comment: You need to call a javascript to run in NodeJS from your Java app to render your dust templates. This can be done by calling node programatically from the command line. Dust operates pretty much the same in Node as it does in the browser, it's just that you're returning the rendered template to your Java app as opposed to inserting it into the DOM in the browser.

Comment: Hi Simon, can you give me detail about this. Actually, i dont know how to begin this. Coz I'm new with Java so I don't know how call nodeJS from java.

Comment: I'm not a Java guy so I can't really help you here. I must say though that I don't think using Dust as your primary tool for rendering in a Java app is a good idea. You'd be much better off using a java specific template language. Dust is used on the server when you are using javascript as your server language or on the browser when you are building a client-side app, or have need of more complex client side template (as apposed to simple HTML strings). I'm sorry, that's the best I can give you.